# Use NUXT for SSR optimization, when multiple dynamic pages are opened, the async interfaces block each other

Tags: async-await, nuxt.js

My NUXT version is 2.15.8,For SSR optimization I used Async Data

```
async asyncData(data) {
let pagePromise = await Promise.all([queryXXX, geXXX, getXXX, queryXXX, getXXX])
      return {
        XX1: pagePromise[0].data,
        XX2: pagePromise[0].data.proImgList.slice(0, 3),
        XX3: pagePromise[0].data.proImgList.slice(0, 3),
        XX4: pagePromise[1].data || [],
        XX5: pagePromise[2].data,
        XX6: pagePromise[3].data,
        XX7: pagePromise[4].data
      }
}
```

This method is used to obtain data from multiple interfaces at the same time for rendering pages

There is no problem with a single page, but when I open multiple dynamic pages with different data at the same time, their loading will block each other

What should I modify to rule out clogging issues?